# Painless Script update fails to actually update the document

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document in ES. A field named "site" which is currently having value as "Elasticsearch". I want to update the value of this field to "stackOverFlow". I am using below script for the same.

"script": {
"lang": "painless",
"inline": "for (k in params.keySet()){if (!k.equals('ctx')){ctx._source.put(k,   params.get(k))}}"
},
"params":{
"site":"stackOverFlow"
}

I am getting success in my response and the _version is getting increased by 1. But still my document is not getting updated. The value of site remains as "Elasticsearch".

NOTE : I am using ES version 6.4

Can anyone help me in figuring out where it goes wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"params" field should be included within the script. Move the braces before "params" to the end.

Below ES query works for me!

```
POST /itest/_doc/1/_update
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline": "for (k in params.keySet()){if (!k.equals('ctx')){ctx._source.put(k, params.get(k))}}",
    "params": {
      "site": "stackOverFlow"
    }
  }
}
```